# Error while executing gradle command in docker file

Tags: docker, gradle, docker-compose, dockerfile, gradlew

```
FROM gradle:4.2.1-jdk8-alpine
WORKDIR /app
ADD --chown=gradle:gradle /app/producer /app
RUN ./gradlew build --stacktrace
```

Project Structure is as follows . **It is a muti module project**:

```
 <code>
        --springbootdocker (Root folder of project) <br>
          --producer (Sub module Producer) <br> 
            -- Dockerfile (for Producer)<br>
          --consumer (Sub module Consumer) <br>
            -- Dockerfile (for Consumer)<br
    </code>
```

This is the docker file. 
While doing docker build: getting this error

> failed to build: ADD failed: stat
>   /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder561553413/app/producer: no such
>   file or directory

Comment: show you directory sturcture. Also I do the source path in your `ADD` instruction should be inside the context of the build.

Comment: @michalk I have added the project structure

Comment: @stephenfernandes What is `myProject` directory here?

Comment: @hariK the folder is producer. My bad not mentioning it correctly

Comment: @hariK the same error ...it is still going to .../var/lib/docker/.....................

Answer (score 2):

Here you have to fix a couple of things in your Dockerfile.

1. `ADD` command
    `ADD` command requires two parameters `<src> and <dest>`. So, you should provide `producer` path from the host as src container path as dest. But in such cases recommended to use `COPY` command.

   `COPY --chown=gradle:gradle producer /app/producer`
2. `RUN ./gradlew`
    It should be just `gradle` and it's `WORKDIR` should be `/app/producer`. If not it'll fail and you'll get,

   `Failed to create parent directory '/app/.gradle' when creating directory 
   '/app/.gradle/4.2.1/fileHashes'` error when running `gradle` command.
   Because the `WORKDIR /app` owns by user `root`.
3. Recommend to divide `RUN gradle build --stacktrace` as `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`.

   Complete Dockerfile

```
FROM gradle:4.2.1-jdk8-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle producer /app/producer
WORKDIR /app/producer
ENTRYPOINT ["gradle"]
CMD ["build", "--stacktrace"]
```

The partial output of `docker build`

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
:buildEnvironment

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

classpath
No dependencies

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Comment: somehow this solution didnt work for me .Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b
Java : 8. These are my versions.

Comment: @stephenfernandes What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

This is the dockerfile which is currently working without any error.

```
FROM gradle:4.10.0-jdk8-alpine AS build
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src/producer
WORKDIR /home/gradle/src/producer
RUN gradle bootJar --no-daemon --stacktrace
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/*.jar
COPY --from=build /home/gradle/src/producer/build/libs/*.jar producer.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/producer.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

ADDed files need to be under the directory where the docker build is being run from, so depending on your structure you probably want something like:

```
ADD myProject /app
```

Assuming you have a structure like:

```
Dockerfile
myProject/
```

Comment: I have added the directory structure. Can you please suggest now

Comment: producer and consumer  have to be in the same directory as their respective dockerfiles.  You can only add files and directories that are below the directory where the dockerfile is built. And the path should be relative to the location


ADD producer /app